# First button click, change colour, Second click change font family

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple HTML with a paragraph and button. I want to carry out different commands on every click of the button. For first click, change paragraph colour, on second click change font family, on third click copy the innerHTML 5 times(pls explain how to do this), on four or more clicks, change innerHTML to "DONE".

```js
var clicks = 0;
var a = document.getElementById("output");

function go() {
    clicks ++;
    moves();
};

function moves() {
  if (clicks = 1) {
a.style.color = "red";
 }
   else if (clicks = 2) {
a.style.fontFamily = "sans-serif";
  }

 }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
   <title></title>
 </head>
<body>
<button onclick=go();>ClickMe</button>
<p id="output">Change Me</p>
</body>
<script src="q2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: [Equality Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Using_the_Equality_Operators) are `==` or `===`, not `=`. When you do `if (clicks = 1)`, for example, you're *setting* `clicks` to `1`, not comparing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have used `=` instead of `==`.`=` are used for assignment and for compare you must use `==` or `===`.
also you don't need to move function and I moved it to go function

```js
var clicks = 0;
var a = document.getElementById("output");

function go() {
    clicks ++;
    if (clicks == 1) {
       a.style.color = "red";
 }
   if (clicks == 2) {
      a.style.fontFamily = "sans-serif";
  }
   if (clicks == 3) {
      a.innerText = a.innerText+a.innerText+a.innerText+a.innerText;
  }
   if (clicks == 4) {
      a.innerText = "done";
  }
};
```

```html
<body>
<button onclick=go();>ClickMe</button>
<p id="output">Change Me</p>
</body>
```

Comment: I also fixed `=` problems

Comment: @Santi I also added some explain of my solution. Thanks for your mention :)

Comment: Yup this is exactly what i was looking for. I knew I was doing it right, just missed something very simple. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a queue - implemented by a simple array - of functions like below (just a simplified example which you can base on):

```
var changeColor = function() {
  a.style.color = "red";
};

var changeFont = function() {
  a.style.fontFamily = "sans-serif";
};

var moves = [changeColor, changeColor, changeFont, changeFont, changeFont];

function go() {
  var move = moves.shift(); // get and remove the first move from the queue
  if (move) move();
}
```

The idea is storing the moves in that queue in the order you want to execute them. So, if you want a certain function to be executed 4 times, you put it 4 times in the queue, followed by the next function in the amount you want, and so on and so forth.

The `shift` function gets the next move to be executed. You need to call only that function, `go`, to execute the next move.

With this approach, you don't need to count the number of clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like an array of functions. See the comments for explanation under every function.

```js
$(function () {
  // Let's start with an array of functions that needs to be executed.
  var fns = [function () {
    // First one.
    // Change Para Colour.
    $("#output").css("color", "#00f");
  }, function () {
    // Second one.
    // Change Para Font.
    $("#output").css("font-family", "monospace");
  }, function () {
    // Third one.
    // Copy the inner HTML 5 times. You can use something like String.repeat().
    $("#output").html($("#output").html().repeat(5));
  }, function () {
    // Fourth one.
    // Done.
    $("#output").html("Done.");
  }];
  var counter = 0;
  $("button").click(function () {
    if (counter >= 4)
      return false;
    fns[counter]();
    counter++;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>ClickMe</button>
<p id="output">Change Me</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea, but you are missing the actual `click` event handling registration.

Also, it's cleaner and easier to maintain if you add/remove CSS classes, rather than modifying individual styles.

Lastly, because of the particular `if` logic you have, a `switch` statement is easier to read and slightly better in performance.

```js
var clicks = 1;
var o = document.getElementById("output");
var b = document.getElementById("btn");

// Store original text
var original = o.textContent;

// Set up a click event handler:
b.addEventListener("click", moves);

function moves() {

  switch (clicks) {
    case 1:
      o.classList.add("one");
      break;
    case 2:
      o.classList.add("two");
      o.classList.remove("one");
      o.textContent = repeatText(5, o.textContent);
      break;
    case 3:
      o.classList.add("three");
      o.classList.remove("two");
      o.textContent = original;    
      break;
    case 4:
      // Intentional fall-through to the default
    default:
      o.classList.remove("three"); 
      o.textContent = "Done";
      break;   
  }
  
  // Can't have a space before or after ++
  clicks++;

 }
 
 function repeatText(numTimes, data){
   var result = "";
   for(var i = 0; i < numTimes; i++){
     result += data;
   }
   return result;
 }
```

```css
.one {
  color:red;
}

.two {
  font-family:sans-serif;
}

.three {
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">ClickMe</button>
<p id="output">Change Me</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use repeated to make 5 copies and store it in a variable.

```js
const content = document.getElementById('content');

let copy5;
let count = 0;
content.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  count += 1;
  if (count === 1) {
    content.style.color = 'green';
  }
  if (count === 2) {
    content.style.fontFamily = "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"
  }
  if (count === 3) {
    copy5 = content.innerText.repeat(5);
    console.log(copy5)
  }
  if (count === 4) {
    content.innerHTML = 'DONE';
    count = 0;
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="content">I have a simple HTML with a paragraph and button. I want to carry out different commands on every click of the button. For first click, change paragraph colour, on second click change font family, on third click copy the innerHTML 5 times(pls explain
  how to do this), on four or more clicks, change innerHTML to "DONE".</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

as far i understood from your question, the below code can work fine for you... in your question it said  "on third click copy the innerHTML 5 times", loop the same function for the 5 times.

```
var count = 0;
function go(){
    count++;
    switch(count){
        case 1: document.getElementById('output').style.color = 'green'; break;
        case 2: document.getElementById('output').style.fontFamily = 'sans-serif'; break;
        case 3: copyText('output'); break;
        case 4: document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = '"DONE"';
    }
}
function copyText(containerid){
    if (document.selection) { 
        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
        range.select().createTextRange();
        document.execCommand("Copy"); 

    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        var range = document.createRange();
         range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
         window.getSelection().addRange(range);
         document.execCommand("Copy");
    }
}
```